# Python - keeping counter inside list comprehension

Tags: python, counter, list-comprehension

Is it possible to write a list comprehension for the following loop?

```
m = []
counter = 0
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if x.field == 'something':
        counter += 1
        m.append(counter / i)
```

I do not know how to increment the counter inside the list comprehension.

Comment: Note that this can result in division by zero if the first (i.e. "zeroth") element satisfies the condition. Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are right. I wrote that code on the fly and I forget to increment by 1 i. I want to compute the [average precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Average_precision)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use an [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
import itertools as IT
counter = IT.count(1)
[next(counter)/i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x.field == 'something']
```

To avoid the possible ZeroDivisionError pointed out by tobias_k, you could make `enumerate` start counting from 1 by using `enumerate(l, start=1)`:

```
[next(counter)/i for i, x in enumerate(l, start=1) 
 if x.field == 'something']
```